# Thread Safe File Writer Debugger objective c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, io

I'm trying to achieve a thread safe file io as a debugger with the following code:

.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DebugLogsHelper : NSObject
+ (instancetype)sharedManager;
- (void)WriteLogWithString:(NSString *)message;
- (void)ApplicationStart;
@end
```

.m file:

```
 #import "DebugLogsHelper.h"

 @interface DebugLogsHelper()

 @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t concurrentLogsQueue;

 @end

 @implementation DebugLogsHelper

 + (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static DebugLogsHelper *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    sharedManager = [[DebugLogsHelper alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Singleton has memory address at: %@", sharedManager);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
});
return sharedManager;
}
- (NSString*)CurrentSystemTime {
return [[NSDate date] description];
}

-(NSString*)getDocumentsPath
{
      NSString *path  =   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
return path;
}

- (NSString*)getLogFilePath
{
NSString *loggingFilePath = nil;

loggingFilePath = [[self getDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/CSDebugLog.txt"];
return loggingFilePath;
}

- (void)ApplicationStart
{

[self WriteLogWithString:@"==============APP START: %@=============="];
}
- (void)WriteLogWithString:(NSString *)message
{
dispatch_barrier_async(self.concurrentLogsQueue, ^{ // 2
    if(message != nil){

        NSString *locationFilePath = [self getLogFilePath];

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %s [Line %d]: %@", [self CurrentSystemTime],__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__,message];
        FILE *fp = fopen([locationFilePath UTF8String], "a");

        fprintf(fp,"%s\n", [str UTF8String]);

        fclose(fp);
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 4
        //[self postContentAddedNotification];
    });
});
}
@end
```

and I'm getting the attached (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) error when calling this code from a view controller:

```
debugInfo = [DebugLogsHelper sharedManager];
[debugInfo ApplicationStart];
```

[image]

Comment: How is `concurrentLogsQueue` set up?

Comment: What's with all the sleeping?